# Is there any configurable option to stop uploading the recorded script to the Blaze meter cloud using Blaze meter chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

The security team in our company raised a concern on the Blaze meter chrome extension recorder regarding the automatic upload the recorded script into Blaze meter cloud. So looking for options like

1. Do we have any configurable option to turn off the automatic upload of the recorded scripts to the Blazemeter cloud??
2. If we turn off the upload, can we still be able to download the recorded script into a jmx file?

Appreciate your time in reading and any valuable suggestion. Thanks

I did try researching on the Blaze meter website and university but couldn't find much any option

Answer (score 0):

As per [The BlazeMeter Chrome Extension: Record JMeter, Selenium, or Synchronized JMeter and Selenium](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) article:

> Note: The extension needs to be able to communicate with blazemeter.com in order for the recording to be converted into a script.

so there is no "configurable option", if recorded script contains sensitive information which cannot go outside your local Intranet you won't be able to use BlazeMeter Chrome Extension for recording. Consider going for [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) instead.